# Error Import a MXNet model Export by Mathematica in 11.2 and 11.3

Tags: neural-networks, mxnet-format

the model was trained by

`net = NetModel["Inception V1 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data"]`

```
Export["model.json",model,"MXNet"]
model.json
 Import["model.json",{"MXNet","Net"}]
During evaluation of Import::invmxlayer: Layer named "1.pool1_3x3_s2_pad$0" couldn't be created, layer type "Pad" is not supported.
$Failed
```

So sad

So we cann't import many models into Mathematica.

Comment: Since the [documentation here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MXNet.html) declare it is a invertible convert.then I don't think something wrong.

Comment: @yoda bad news. I think Mathematica implements some stat-of-art models, should support this manipulation as new features..

Comment: You didn't spell @yode 's name correctly.  Maybe you can try again?

Comment: @QuantumDot Copy yours. :)

Answer (score 4):

There are two function `` GeneralUtilities`MLExport `` and `` GeneralUtilities`MLImport `` to do export and import thing.But it cannot produce that `.params` file.Maybe it can help.

```
net = NetModel["Inception V1 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data"];
GeneralUtilities`MLExport["test.json", net]
```

> `"test.json"`

Then you can import it.

```
netin = GeneralUtilities`MLImport["test.json"]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice find. I can't wait for ONNX support.